# Connected scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need help connecting the dots with lines for this graph:

[image]

this is my code:

```py
country_stats.plot(kind='line',
                   x="GDP per capita",
                   y='Life satisfaction',
                   color='blue',
                   figsize=(8,3))
plt.axis([0, 110000, 0, 10])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `style='.-'` as kwarg for `country_stats.plot()`.

**Edit:**

Given that you already have `colors` in `pandas.DataFrame.plot()`, add `marker='.-'` instead of `style='.-'`.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, i only got the lines

Comment: `df1.plot(style='bo-')`

Comment: I guess `country_stats` is `pandas` DataFrame. In that case, you can use the `style` kwarg to the `country_stats.plot`.

Comment: I keep getting the following error: Cannot pass 'style' string with a color symbol and 'color' keyword argument. Please use one or the other or pass 'style' without a color symbol

Comment: @Rachel I'm not too familiar with DataFrame `plot`, so I wasn't sure whether `pd.DataFrame.plot(style)` and `plt.plot(style)` operated similarly. Try `marker='.-'` instead of `style='.-'`.